# vb.net adding row to databound datagridview (list of T)

Tags: vb.net, list, datagridview

i have two databound datagridviews, each one is bound to a List(Of MyType).

Now i want to add the selectedrows (the selected MyTypes) to the other datagridview.

Till now, i made it like:
- iterating through selectedrows property
- constructing a new item of MyType and getting the Properties of the current Row

Is there a better method of doing this?

Can i easily check if the item already exists? Maybe its better to only move the data between the lists?

Thanks!!

Comment: The first thing to ask yourself is whether you want the list bound to the second grid to contain different objects to the first but contain the same data or the same objects.  At the moment you're creating new objects but that is unnecessary unless you want to modify the objects in one list without affecting the other.

Comment: Yup, the last thing u mentioned is exactly what i want. I would Not use 2 different bindinglists if i would just need one.. I need 2 lists where i can move the items from one to the other and eventually back. In Addition i need to take care for duplicates.

Comment: So, you're saying that you want to be able to create a copy of an item in the first list and add it to the second, modify it, then create a copy of the modified object and add it back to the first list?  If that's what you're saying then what you say you're doing is basically what you have to do.  There may be some optimisations possible in your code but, as we haven't seen the code, we couldn't really say for sure.

Comment: Im making a  Kind of a quiz, there you have questions as you might know ;).. a user can create a new list,  in this Form the user is able to see all possible questions and can move selected questions to the other list. For sure i dont want to have Double entries, so I thought it would be better to move the question from the first datagridview-source to the second one. This way im avoiding to check for double entries. If that doesnt work, i would delete the moved item afterwards in the source list. If a user removes an item again, then i have to Put it back to the source list.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how people get anything done when they don't understand what they want to do enough to explain it clearly.  So it now appears that you don't want to modify the items.  Can you just state clearly one way ore the other?  Also, when an item gets put in the second list, does it get removed from the first list?  Your most recent comment suggests it does but you never mentioned that before.

Comment: In the Main Post there is written "or only move the data.", moving means from place a to b and that means the moved thing is no more at place a. That means yes, is has to be removed from the source, doesnt matter which way its moved. Modifying the items doesnt matter in First place. If i want to change the items i add the inotifypropertychanged interface and that'll Do it. Im sorry if it wasnt clear, but in my opinion i thought id say it clear 'nough. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to use a use a data source that supports filtering, e.g. a `DataTable`, you will need two lists.  There's no need for creating copies of objects though; you simply move the object from one bound list to the other.  I'd suggest that you bind your two lists to `BindingSource` components and bind them to the grids.  You can then do something like this:

```
'Get the bound item from each of the selected rows in the first grid.
Dim selectedItems = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.
                                     Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
                                     Select(Function(row) row.DataBoundItem).
                                     Cast(Of YourItemType).
                                     ToArray()

'Move the selected items from the first list to the second.
For Each item In selectedItems
    list1.Remove(item)
    list2.Add(item)
Next

'Refresh both grids.
Me.BindingSource1.ResetBindings(False)
Me.BindingSource2.ResetBindings(False)
```